# When display type of field can be integer or long?

Tags: data-types, displaytype

I am building a managed package for our clients which include custom filter and custom sorting of records, I need to consider different cases regarding to field types and display types.

I know that there are several different Display Type values, like `DisplayType.Integer` and `DisplayType.Long`, but I don't understand if I can test such values.

Are there any fields which have display types of Integer or Long?
Even if I try to create a number field with 0 Decimal Places and with Length of 9 or 18, the resulting DisplayType of such field is still Double, but not Number or Long.

Maybe there is some standard field type that have such DisplayType?

Answer (score 1):

We need to run two snippets of code to find out any instances of `Long` and `Integer` DisplayTypes.

Long:

```
Set<Schema.DisplayType> displayTypes = new Set<Schema.DisplayType>();

Map<String,SObjectType> stuff = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

for (SObjectType theType : stuff.values()) {
    Map<String, SObjectField> theFields = theType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    
    for (SObjectField theField : theFields.values()) {
        displayTypes.add(theField.getDescribe().getType());
        
        if (theField.getDescribe().getType() == DisplayType.Long) {
            System.debug('Type ' + theType.getDescribe().name + ' has long ' + theField.getDescribe().name);
        }
    }
}
```

In result we can see that there are two fields which have Long Display Data Type:

```
Type AppAnalyticsQueryRequest has long DownloadSize
Type PlatformEventUsageMetric has long Value
```

And Integer:

```
Set<Schema.DisplayType> displayTypes = new Set<Schema.DisplayType>();

Map<String,SObjectType> stuff = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

for (SObjectType theType : stuff.values()) {
    Map<String, SObjectField> theFields = theType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    
    for (SObjectField theField : theFields.values()) {
        displayTypes.add(theField.getDescribe().getType());
        
        if (theField.getDescribe().getType() == DisplayType.Integer) {
            System.debug('Type ' + theType.getDescribe().name + ' has integer ' + theField.getDescribe().name);
        }
    }
}
```

In result we can see there are a lot of such fields

```
Type Asset has integer AssetLevel
Type AssetFeed has integer CommentCount
```

etc